# Python "Event" equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, python, multithreading

What's the closest thing in Java (perhaps an idiom) to [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects) in Python?

Comment: i ended up with: http://github.com/shikhar/sshj/tree/master/src/main/java/net/schmizz/concurrent/

Comment: Using a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Void>` with a capacity of 1 also works great for many use cases. `offer()` is `set()` on `Event` and `take()` is `wait()` followed by `clear()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Object.wait()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) [`Object.notify()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())/[`Object.notifyAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()).

Or [`Condition.await()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()) and [`Condition.signal()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal())/[`Condition.signalAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signalAll()) for Java 5+.

**Edit:** Because the python specification is similar how we usually wait a Java implementation would look like this:

```
class Event {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
    boolean flag;
    public void doWait() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!flag) {
                cond.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void doWait(float seconds) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!flag) {
                cond.await((int)(seconds * 1000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public boolean isSet() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return flag;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void set() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            flag = true;
            cond.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void clear() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            flag = false;
            cond.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't suggest wait() and notify(). Somebody might use them.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with java.util.concurrent.Condition

Comment: Just saw your edit with the example Event implementation, wonderful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The python event's wait method returns a boolean (false in case of a timeout, true otherwise). Would be great if this implementation also did that.

Answer (score 0):

A [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226455/can-anyone-explain-thread-monitors-and-wait). There is a comment on the accepted answer which suggests a [Semaphore](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or a [Latch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Not the same semantics as the above implementation, but handy.

Comment: Note that the operational behavior of the Semaphore differs from the Event object you asked.